# How to strikethrough selected text in JTextPane? (java)

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, strikethrough

Title says it all. Let's say I have a right-click menu with "Strikethrough selected text" option. When I have selected some text in jtextpane, right-click --> "Strikethrough selected text" , and the selected text gets strikedthrough.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://java-sl.com/tip_colored_strikethrough.html see the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing text components use `Actions` to provide the various formatting features of a text pane.

Following is the code for the `UnderlineAction` of the `StyledEditorKit`.

```
public static class UnderlineAction extends StyledTextAction {

    /**
     * Constructs a new UnderlineAction.
     */
    public UnderlineAction() {
        super("font-underline");
    }

    /**
     * Toggles the Underline attribute.
     *
     * @param e the action event
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JEditorPane editor = getEditor(e);
        if (editor != null) {
            StyledEditorKit kit = getStyledEditorKit(editor);
            MutableAttributeSet attr = kit.getInputAttributes();
            boolean underline = (StyleConstants.isUnderline(attr)) ? false : true;
            SimpleAttributeSet sas = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setUnderline(sas, underline);
            setCharacterAttributes(editor, sas, false);
        }
    }
}
```

So basically you will need to create your own "StrikeThroughAction" by replacing the "underline" StyleConstants methods to use the "strikethrough" StyleConstants methods.

Once you create a Action you can then use the Action by creating a JMenuItem or JButton with the Action. When the component is clicked the strike through attribute will then be added to the selected text.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! That's 99% the result I want to achieve.
As the code comments you gave me above says, the action **Toggles** the underline attribute. The way I want to use it is: Select some text then right click--> strikethrough. The selected text gets strikedthrough and I can keep typing normal text(no strikethrough).

Comment: **Edit:** I forgot to mention: I don't want to use it as a single action(using a right click menu option to toggle it), but to use it in some other method(doing more stuff in there).

Answer (score 0):

in your right click action

```
objJTextPane.setContentType( "text/html" );
String[] args = objJTextPane.getText().split(objJTextPane.getSelectedText());
objJTextPane.setText("<strike>" + objJTextPane.getSelectedText() + "</strike>"+ args[1].toString());
```

apply your logic in splitting string.

Comment: I'm not using html tags.